# Flair avatar wrong size

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, profile-picture

I was about to link to my flair, when I noticed my avatar doesn't quite fit...

> This looks like a bug with the new upload-your-own feature; you are not using a Gravatar image, and that's where this is going wrong

Screencap:
[image: user profile]

Flair as seen by others here on Meta (no image at all):
[image]

Comment: Unicorns are far too awesome to be contained within flair.

Comment: @Bart I hope that's not an intended feature xD

Comment: The combined flair manages it just fine: http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1420160.png (just observing what works and what doesn't).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, but I want to link to my StackOverflow flair.

Comment: This looks like a bug with the new upload-your-own feature; you are not using a gravatar image, and that's where this is going wrong.

Comment: What is also interesting is that not only does the combo-flair use the same image, and sized it correctly, but your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1420160/djdavid98) shows a gravatar image instead (which is totally different).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I does not seem to be able to edit my network profile avatar.

Comment: @DJDavid98: It takes that info from your oldest account in the network, automatically. Obviously, the new imgur-hosted avatar images are not (yet) included in that sync.

Comment: Also of note is that the live version doesn't show *any* avatar image for me; just the yellow 'attach photo here' square. I've added it to your post, it is probably relevant. This only applies to the hotdog theme, the other images on your [Stack Overflow flair page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1344955/djdavid98/flair) still show the oversized version.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, looks like I'm now officially screwed.

Comment: @DJDavid98: You officially will get Meta reputation for discovering an actual bug, that the SE team will be grateful for receiving and fixing for you ASAP. :-)

Comment: @DJDavid98: In the meantime, you can still use Gravatar to get a decently-sized flair back, of course. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess... xD And I use gravatar on other pages too, where I would like to keep it as-is. I'll just wait for the SE team then, thanks.

Comment: @DJDavid98: you don't have a second email address you can attach a gravatar to? If you use gmail, for example, it's trivial to create special email addresses for purposes like these.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't feel like trying to get that working. I will just wait for SE to fix "itself".

Comment: looks same to me .. even its not showing image in default theme http://i.stack.imgur.com/0vvcA.png

Comment: Hrm. http://i.imgur.com/BHftGla.png

Comment: I'm kind of surprised no action has been taken by the SO team yet. This bug seems to affect quite a few users.

Comment: @DJDavid98 the team got lots of work and they have their own schedule; trivial bugs are fixed ultra fast guess this one isn't so trivial and they got more important things in their list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)... probably, with the next build.

We couldn't quite reproduce this, but we narrowed it down to a possibly buggy line of code.  Having fixed that up, this is most likely fixed.  We'll know in a day or so (after the next build) when flair starts getting re-rendered as it falls out of cache.