# Non-Gravatar avatars aren't supported on StackExchange.com global profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, gravatar, network-profile, profile-picture

The StackExchange.com global profile still uses Gravatar with the email address from your primary account, even if that account isn't using Gravatar itself.

For example, [my global profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/851/jeremy-banks) is synced with my Stack Overflow acount, yet it displays my Gravatar:

> [image]

Even though [my Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy-banks) is using an avatar that was directly uploaded:

> [image]

---

The correct avatar *is* used in the global flair.

> [image]

The global flair also displays it *correctly*, which though [the my site-specific flair does not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163583/flair-avatar-wrong-size):

> [image]

Comment: I just saw that my observations here were an echo of [comments made on this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163583/flair-avatar-wrong-size).

Comment: I have the same issue... :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network profile now shows your updated profile image, whether it be hosted on Gravatar or elsewhere:

> [image]

Comment: I still don't see my uploaded profile on other StackExchange sites... :|

Comment: @Fall To copy a change to all your accounts, you have to click the "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" button on your edit profile page. (I just did it for you.)